# I can't post my data in Mysql, how to fix that?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I implemented jbpm business process in my springboot application and I am using its methods.
I can't post my data in Mysql, I am using methods from another generated  java classes and I need to use them.
How can I change my code in the controller in the way that I can use these methods?

This is the Controller

'''

```
package com.iway.app.rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.iway.app.rest.model.EvaluationRequest;
import com.iway.rest.businesscentral.handler.ApiClient;
import com.iway.rest.businesscentral.handler.ProcessInstancesApi;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;


@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class EvaluationRestController {
    
    //@Autowired
    //private ApiClient apiClient; 
    
    @Autowired
    private ProcessInstancesApi processInstancesApi;
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @PostMapping("/evaluation")
    public ResponseEntity startEvaluationProcess(@RequestBody EvaluationRequest evaluationRequest) {
        
        Long process = processInstancesApi.startProcess("evaluation_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT", "evaluation", evaluationRequest.toString());
        System.out.println("Processus Started : "+process);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(process);
    }

}
'''
```

This is the Repository
'''

```
package com.iway.app.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.iway.app.rest.model.EvaluationRequest;


public interface EvaluationRepository extends JpaRepository<EvaluationRequest, Long>{
}
```

'''

This is the Model

'''

```
package com.iway.app.rest.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Evaluation")
public class EvaluationRequest implements Serializable  {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    
    
    @JsonProperty("employee")
    private String employee;
    @JsonProperty("reason")
    private String reason;
     private long id;
    
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
      public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
      
      @Column(name = "employee", nullable = false)
    public String getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }




    public void setEmployee(String employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }



      @Column(name = "reason", nullable = false)
    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }




    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }




    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }
    
    

    
    
    

}
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to save your parameters into the model class and call save function from repository class. Ex.

```
@Autowired
EvaluationRepository  er;
```

Under ur System.out.println("Processus Started : "+process);

```
er.save(yourmodelclass);
```

Please refer this : https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-restful-crud-api-examples-with-mysql-database